# Un-highlight Blog Menu Item when Category Menu Item is Selected

Tags: posts, functions, categories, menus, blog

[image]

On a site I'm working on, I am using a blog category called **'Podcast'** for any podcasts that are posted. I have this as a menu item as pictured. My only issue is, that when I click podcast (just a link to `/blog/category/podcast/` it highlights both the Blog and Podcast menu items (pictured above), which makes sense, as each podcast is technically a blog post.

What I'm looking to accomplish is make it so that the blog menu item is not highlighted whenever one is at the Podcast link (`/blog/category/podcast/`) or when one is looking at a blog post with the sole category being **'Podcast'**. I currently have a child theme but have been stumped as to what code I would need in my functions.php to allow me to accomplish this. I appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: You might not need to do it in functions.php. This behaviour can probably be changed using CSS. If you could post a link to your site, I might be able to help.

Comment: I was thinking I would potentially have to use functions.php to change the css conditionally. However, I'd love a css only way if that's possible.

Site is here http://bit.do/podcastlink

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what can see on your website, the *Blog* page is highlighted in a same way as a Podcast page because it has a class 'current_page_parent' that has the same styling in CSS as a 'current-menu-item' which is used on a *Podcast* menu item.

This means that the *Podcast* page is a child page of a Blog page. So there are two possible solutions for your problem in this case.

**Solution 1.**

Make the *Podcast* page a stand-alone (not child) page. Then this class will disappear with unwanted styling.

**Solution 2.**

If changing page hierarchy is not an option, add this CSS using a child theme, or Custom CSS plugin ([like this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/)):

```
.header.white .topnav li.current_page_parent > a {
    opacity: 0.75 !important;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

This will revert the styles applied to that menu item.

**Update 10/26/2016**

As per your follow-up question, the snippet will look like this:

```
.category-podcast .header.white .topnav li.current_page_parent>a {
    opacity: 0.75 !important;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Now it will work only on a podcast category archive.

Comment: Wow, thank you Dmitry. I should've been aware of the current_page_parent selector! The solution 2 was exactly what I was looking for, and is an ideal option given my current child theme. Cheers, and thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Dmitry, sorry to bother you again. I wanted to inquire as to whether or not you knew a good way to make the "blog" link also highlight when an individual non-podcast is clicked.

Comment: Basically, your solution works great, the only downside, is the blog menu link is now not highlighted whenever one is on a blog post (of category not podcast).

Comment: Sorry for delay. I've updated the answer. Now it should work.